# How to read in the third word of c++ stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I've been given a document, from which I need to read certain important information into my C++ program. These information are given in the following style:

> KEYWORD : VALUE_OF_KEYWORDS_TYPE

where *VALUE_OF_KEYWORDS_TYPE* usually cointains an integer value. I use the following scheme to read this value into my program:

```
int variable_to_store_value = 0;
std::string content_of_line = "";
std::getline(file,content_of_line);
std::stringstream stream(content_of_line);
std::string threshold;
stream >> threshold >> threshold >> variable_to_store_value ;
```

using the *threshold* variable seems kinda expandable to me, but I'm not sure what the most correct way for solving this problem would be... Also let me know, if there is a more efficient way in terms of runtime for these things.
Thank you very much in advance for trying to help me with my problem!

Comment: Looks like you are already doing what you ask.

Comment: ***if there is a more efficient way in terms of runtime for these things*** That may depend on your hardware after very careful profiling of your application and operating system. Your compiler should already do a good job of optimizing your code.

Comment: "expandable" -> "expendable" ? Though I dont see the problem with reading the first two words and ignore them when thats exactly what you want to do. Only if `KEYWORD :` is of fixed and known lenght you can use a shortcut

Comment: `there is a more efficient way in terms of runtime for these things` There is... but do you care about efficiency that much? Have you profiled your code and is reading that particular string a bootleneck in your program? Remember about first 2 [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). Prefer readable code that has no bugs. Btw, just read from the `file`, why use `getline+stringstream`?

Comment: I second KamilCuk. If this code is executed once to read something from a file then "efficient" is much more about simple, readably, maintainability rather than squeezing some ms out of runtime

Answer (score 2):

> using the `threshold` variable seems kinda expandable to me, but I'm not sure what the most correct way for solving this problem would be...

I would suggest simply getting rid of the `threshold` variable altogether and instead use the `stream.ignore()` method to skip what you don't want, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

std::string content_of_line;
if (std::getline(file, content_of_line)) {
    std::istringstream stream(content_of_line);
    stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ':');
    int variable_to_store_value = 0;
    if (stream >> variable_to_store_value) {
        // use variable_to_store_value as needed...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the `stream` variable, too:

```cpp
#include <limits>

if (file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ':')) {
    int variable_to_store_value = 0;
    if (stream >> variable_to_store_value) {
        // use variable_to_store_value as needed...
    }
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```